# How do input characters into an array through user input?

Tags: java, arrays, char, user-input

This is essentially what i have, everything works fine, but for some reason I'm not able to input the characters into the array.

If you could explain to me why it isn't working it would be greatly appreciated. 
The purpose of this is to input a series of characters into an array, and to count the number of  ' ' (gaps) present within it.

The part in bold is where I'm currently having my issue.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test4c{
  public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);

    int size;

    System.out.println("Please input the size of the array.");
    size = x.nextInt();

    char[] test = new char[size];

    System.out.println("Please input " + size + " characters.");
  //ask user to input number of characters

    for(int i = 0; i<size; i++){
      **test[i] = a.next().toCharArray();**
    }

    int s;
    int e;


    System.out.println("Please input the starting value of the search.");
    s = x.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Please input the ending value of the search.");
    e = x.nextInt();


  }

  public static int spaceCount(char[]arr, int s, int e){
    int count = 0;

    if (s<= e) {
      count = spaceCount(arr,s+1, e);
      /*counter set up to cause an increase of "s" so
       * the array is traversed until point "e"*/

      if (arr[s] == ' ' ) {
        count++;
      }
    }

    return count;// return the number of spaces found
  }
}
```

Comment: do you get any error? can you post up your stack trace?

Comment: Why two Scanner instance?

Comment: `a.next().toCharArray()` <- You are attempting to put a char array into a slot within in an array which can only hold `char`

Comment: BTW, you can't embolden in code blocks - your 'bold' line just shows as having two pairs of asterisks around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you force to run your code, you get such error stack

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable
>   source code - **incompatible types: char[] cannot be converted to char**
>     at test4c.Test4c.main(Test4c.java:26) Java Result: 1

It is obviously clear why you get such a message?

you try to insert a char array inside an index of `char[] test` which **accept a char not a char array**

This is what you have:

```
for(int i = 0; i<size; i++){
      test[i] = a.next().toCharArray();
    }
```

From what you have, I think you want just to convert to `a.next()` to char array which is `test` which you have already defined

```
char[] test = new char[size];
```

you can change what you have to

```
test = a.next().toCharArray();
```

Comment: Thank you very much, my Professor wasn't very clear when it came to explaining concepts in regards to filling arrays with different types.

Comment: @MustaphaMatar you are more than welcome, but please next time, try to provide enough info so other can help you better. Enough info like stack trace good luck

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the `toCharArray` returns an array, and you can't put an array into an array. Try this:

```
Char[] test = a.next().toCharArray();
```